# Using servlets in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, struts2

I wonder if using `servlets` in `Struts 2.3.4` is a good practice or not?

I need to place some html in specific place in `JSP` **without page refreshing**. 
I found 2 ways to achieve this:

1.Create `servlet` and use `AJAX` to handle `POST` request/response, i.e. :

```
<div id="mainDiv">

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#div2').click(function() { 
            $.post('testservlet', function(responseText) {
                $('#mainDiv').html(responseText); 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

2. Call action using `jQuery plugin` and place generated response in target place in `JSP`(using well-known `sx:submit`). The problem is that I do not know how to handle `POST` request/response. `jQuery submit` uses `GET` method.

Could you please tell me which solution is better? In both cases I have access to the `HttpServletRespone` and thanks to that to `PrintWriter` which allows writing `text/html` content to the result `JSP`. So should I use this `PrintWriter` inside Action class or in `servlet` method?

Comment: Why do you specifically need a servlet, I don't understand. Just post your AJAX to an action. No? What's wrong with ` $.post('<s:url action="myAjaxAction"/>'..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `Servlet` here.user simple `Ajax (Jquery)` and let your action handle and send response for you.

`Struts2` actions are capable enough to handle your Ajax request and you are free to use `POST/GET` method as per your requirements.

here is a sample as how to post your data to action class and get response from there

### JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST', // can use GET also
        url : action URL, 
    data : $(formID).serialize(),  // only for POST
    success : function(response) {
         // handle your server response
         $("#MyDiv").html(response);
    },
    error : function(e) {
    // handle error
    }
  });
```

### Action Class

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSuport{

 // define getter and setter for your data

 public String execute() throws Exception{
   // define your logic here
   return Action.SUCCESS;
 }
}
```

### Struts.xml

```
<action name="myAction" class="MyActionClass">
   <result>JSP for success</result>
</action>
```

JSP content will be send back to your Jquery code after the ajax call and you can paste those content to your specified `DIV`.

Also note that `sx:submit` represents `DOJO` tags which are no longer supported in Struts2 and has been deprecated long back.

Using Servelet with Struts2 is not a bad practice provided we have valid use case for that and there are many cases where this is being used, even Struts2 provide a way to let Servlet handle request for your in place of Actions